# Replace default search box in SharePoint 2010 with custom one

Tags: people-search, search, master-page

On every new SharePoint 2010 site you get the default search box (In the MasterPage) that allows you to just do a normal search.

I would like to replace this with some item that will allow you to pick Advanced or People Search first before you search.

Is it possible to replace/alter the default search box in the MasterPage?

Comment: Refer this post... http://www.sharepointoverflow.com/questions/5825/can-we-replace-the-search-box-controls-with-standard-controls-without-using-a-fe

Comment: Similar: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/7038/how-to-configure-two-search-boxes-one-for-people-and-one-for-content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do search scopes cover your requirements?

- [Manage search scopes (SharePoint Server 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee792872.aspx)
- [Help, SharePoint 2010 stole my search scope dropdown!](http://www.rightpointconsulting.com/community/blogs/viewpoint/archive/2010/06/15/help-sharepoint-2010-stole-my-search-scope-dropdown.aspx)

You can also configure the landing page for the search box so you could direct the user to an advanced search page if you like.