# How to configure two search boxes - one for people and one for content?

Tags: search, master-page, people-search

I would like to have two search boxes on my master page, one that would search for content and the other one that would search for people.

I see the code in the master page that searches for content:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderSearchArea" runat="server">
<SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="SmallSearchInputBox" Version="4"/>
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

How would I add another box that searches for people?

Answer (score 5):

You can add a search web part to the page and change the scope to search for people instead.

Comment: Since the delegate control is configured based on the site collection's search settings and scopes you will not be able to add two of these controls to the page and have them behave differently.  Adding the search web part to the page as @CharlieDigital mentioned is the approach I typically take, but this is not done typically done in the masterpage, but on the actual web part page(s).